# Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree and Each child must be laid out exactly once

Tags: flutter

`enter code here`**i have drawer class which has multipages with list of services and inside each page i have add service page with**  `GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey  = GlobalKey<FormState>();`

**my page flow like Drawer -> Utility List page -> add Utility**

**but i m getting error:**

`The following assertion was thrown building Form-[LabeledGlobalKey<FormState>#98e90](state: FormState#bd67c): 'package:flutter/src/widgets/will_pop_scope.dart': Failed assertion: line 135 pos 12: '_route == ModalRoute.of(context)': is not true.`

`======== Exception caught by rendering library ===================================================== Each child must be laid out exactly once.`

`======== Exception caught by widgets library ======================================================= The following assertion was thrown building Overlay-[LabeledGlobalKey<OverlayState>#94fb8](state: OverlayState#45c6b(entries: [OverlayEntry#3a155(opaque: true; maintainState: false), OverlayEntry#62084(opaque: false; maintainState: true), OverlayEntry#c051d(opaque: true; maintainState: false), OverlayEntry#ea85f(opaque: false; maintainState: true), OverlayEntry#6b05f(opaque: true; maintainState: false), OverlayEntry#b940f(opaque: false; maintainState: true)])): 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4954 pos 14: '_dependents.isEmpty': is not true.`

`======== Exception caught by widgets library ======================================================= Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.`

**i have tried many solution but none of them working **

**i have named key differnet according to service**

**addpage:**

```
class AddUtilityBillState extends State<AddUtilityBill>{
     TextEditingController _nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _amountController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _descController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _serviceController = TextEditingController();
  
  GlobalKey<FormState>  utilityFormKey =GlobalKey<FormState>();
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    utilityFormKey.currentState?.dispose();
    super.dispose();

  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)  {
    return Hero(
        tag: widget._tag,
        child: Scaffold(
            floatingActionButtonLocation:
                FloatingActionButtonLocation.miniEndTop,
            floatingActionButton: Container(
            
                child:  FloatingActionButton(
                      heroTag: null,
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (_validate(context)) {
                            _submit(context);
                          }
                        });
                      },
                      backgroundColor: primaryDarkColor,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.done,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      elevation: 0,
                      mini: true,
                    )),
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: primaryColor,
              shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
              title: widget._from.toString().headText(context: context),
              iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            body:
    Form(
    key: utilityFormKey,
    child:
              _form(),
            )));
  }
  
  form() {
    return  Expanded(
            child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: [
            '${Strings.utilityBillTypes} :'
                .bigText(context: context, color: Colors.black54, isBold: true)
                .px16(),
            p10.heightBox,
            widget._serviceModel == null
                ? _utilityBillType()
                : widget._serviceModel.categoryType
                    .bigText(context: context, color: Colors.black87)
                    .px16(),
            Visibility(
                visible: _utilityBillTypeErrorVisible,
                child: (context.isMobile ? p5 : p10).heightBox),
            Visibility(
                visible: _utilityBillTypeErrorVisible,
                child: _utilityBillTypeErrorText
                    .normalText(
                      context: context,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    )
                    .objectTopLeft()
                    .px16()),
            p20.heightBox,
            Row(children: [
              Expanded(
                  child: CustomTextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                controller: _nameController,
                labelText: Strings.name,
                hintText: Strings.enterName,
                validator: (String value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return Strings.emptyName;
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              )),
              p20.widthBox,
              Expanded(
                  child: CustomTextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                controller: _amountController,
                labelText: Strings.amount,
                hintText: Strings.enterAmount,
                validator: (String value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return Strings.emptyAmount;
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ))
            ]).px16(),
            p20.heightBox,
            CustomTextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              controller: _descController,
              labelText: Strings.description,
              hintText: Strings.enterDesc,
            ).px16(),
            p20.heightBox,
            Visibility(
                visible: defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android
                    ? _billTypeClicked2
                    : _billTypeClicked,
                child: CustomTextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  controller: _serviceController,
                  labelText: defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android
                      ? _billTypeItemSelected != null
                          ? _billTypeItemSelected.service
                          : ''
                      : _serviceTypeModelList[_billTypeSelectedIndex].service,
                  hintText: defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android
                      ? _billTypeItemSelected != null
                          ? '${Strings.enterData} ${_billTypeItemSelected.service}'
                          : ''
                      : '${Strings.enterData} ${_serviceTypeModelList[_billTypeSelectedIndex].service}',
                  validator: (String value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return Strings.emptyAmount;
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ).px16()),
            Visibility(
                visible: (_billTypeClicked2 || _billTypeClicked),
                child: p20.heightBox),
            Strings.reminderDateTime
                .bigText(context: context, color: Colors.black54, isBold: true)
                .px16(),
            p20.heightBox,
            Wrap(children: [
              VxBox(
                  child: Icon(
                Icons.date_range_outlined,
                color: primaryColor,
              )).roundedSM.shadowSm.color(Colors.white).p8.make(),
              p15.widthBox,
              InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                    _dateCLicked = true;
                    defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS
                        ? _showDatePicker(context)
                        : _selectDate(context);
                  },
                  child: VxBox(
                          child: (_dateCLicked
                                  ? defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS
                                      ? _chosenDateTime != null
                                          ? DateFormat(Strings.dateFormat)
                                              .format(_chosenDateTime)
                                              .toString()
                                          : Strings.chooseDate
                                      : "${_selectedDate.toLocal()}"
                                          .split(' ')[0]
                                  : Strings.chooseDate)
                              .bigText(context: context, color: Colors.grey)
                              .objectCenter()
                              .px4())
                      .color(Colors.grey[200])
                      .height(p40)
                      .width(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.4)
                      .roundedSM
                      .make())
            ]).px24(),
            Visibility(
                visible: _dateErrorVisible,
                child: (context.isMobile ? p5 : p10).heightBox),
            Visibility(
                visible: _dateErrorVisible,
                child: _dateErrorText
                    .normalText(
                      context: context,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    )
                    .objectCenter()
                    .px16()),
            p20.heightBox,
            Wrap(children: [
              VxBox(
                  child: Icon(
                Icons.access_time_outlined,
                color: primaryColor,
              )).roundedSM.shadowSm.color(Colors.white).p8.make(),
              p15.widthBox,
              InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                    _timeCLicked = true;
                    defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS
                        ? _showTimePicker(context)
                        : _selectTime(context);
                  },
                  child: VxBox(
                          child:
                              (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS
                                      ? _timeIOS != null
                                          ? _timeIOS
                                          : Strings.chooseTime
                                      : _time != null
                                          ? _time
                                          : Strings.chooseTime)
                                  .bigText(context: context, color: Colors.grey)
                                  .objectCenter()
                                  .px4())
                      .color(Colors.grey[200])
                      .height(p40)
                      .width(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.4)
                      .roundedSM
                      .make())
            ]).px24(),
            Visibility(
                visible: _timeErrorVisible,
                child: (context.isMobile ? p5 : p10).heightBox),
            Visibility(
                visible: _timeErrorVisible,
                child: _timeErrorText
                    .normalText(
                      context: context,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    )
                    .objectCenter()
                    .px16()),
            p40.heightBox,
            Button(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (_validate(context)) {
                      _submit(context);
                    }
                  });
                },
                title: Strings.submit),
            Visibility(visible: _isLoading, child: p10.heightBox),
            Visibility(
              visible: _isLoading,
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                backgroundColor: primaryColor,
              ).objectCenter(),
            ),
            p30.heightBox
          ],
        ));
  }
 
 }
```

Comment: Please add your code. it looks like you have used the same key in all the pages. In different forms, use keys with different names. Global keys are defined for the entire project

Comment: i have tried changing the names but it's not working

Comment: plz add your code

Comment: Do you get the error when you go to the add page?

Comment: yes it works for 1 time but when i open page again it throws error

Answer (score 0):

While the error sounds like an issue with your naming GlobalKeys, it's actually a case of duplicate Scaffolds.  It happens when you Navigate to a 2nd page with push, and then instead of popping the 2nd page, you try to push back to the original.  This is trying to create a duplicate Scaffold.

In addition, it can occur when creating a Scaffold inside a Modal.  It's hard to discern in this specific case what's going on, but those are two common causes.